# Can I use the passive voice when talking about sending things?

Tags: passive-voice

Which sentence sounds/looks better, and why:

> You will be sent something.

or

> You will get something.

I'm not a native speaker. The first option in my opinion looks silly, and I have had a problem finding it anywhere on the internet, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. I've taken the liberty of expanding your *sth* to "something". I know some dictionaries use this abbreviation, but it is not standard; and it is a courtesy to the reader to write things out in full. We don't face the same space constraints as dictionary publishers!

Comment: I would rather say "Something will be sent to you." or "You will receive something."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sentences are acceptable, and usually they will have the same practical effect. But they don't mean the same thing:

> **You will be sent X** means that somebody will set the process in motion by directing X toward you.
>
> **You will get X** means that you will end the process by receiving X.

How many times have you said “Hey, you never answered the email I sent you” and gotten back the answer “Hey, I never got it”?

So use active *get* when you're reasonably sure the intended recipient will in fact receive what is being sent. If you're not sure, use *send*—active if you want to name the sender, passive if you don’t.